# C - extracting words from string

Tags: c, string, pointers, extract, words

I'm fairly new to C and therefore encountering quite a bit of confusion with using pointers.

I'm trying to extract words from a string of ASCII characters. 
For instance, if I have the string @@Hello..world>>, I want to get the words "Hello" and "world" out of the string and add them to my linked list.

A word is defined as any sequence of letters, and each word is at most 64 bytes. Also, any character where the function isspace() returns a non-zero value is considered whitespace.

Basically, I'm scanning in the strings from a file using fscanf, then for each string calling my function read_words(char *s) to get the proper words out of the string and add them to my linked list for further use.

Here is my code which seems to be throwing an error that has to do with a pointer.

```
struct node {
    char *val;
    struct node *next;
    int count;
} *words = NULL;


void read_words(char *s)
{
    struct node *tmp;
    char word[64+1];
    int i, check, wordStarted = 0, count = 0;

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
            if ((isspace(s[i]) != 0) || !isalpha(s[i]))
            {
                    if (wordStarted == 1)
                    {
                            check = check_list(word);
                            if (check != 1) {
                                    word[count] = '\0';
                                    tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                                    tmp->val = word;
                                    tmp->count = 1;
                                    tmp->next = words;
                                    words = tmp;
                            }
                            count = 0;
                            wordStarted = 0;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    word[count++] = s[i];
                    wordStarted = 1;
            }
    }

}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Try `strtok`. It splits a string into parts based on any number of splitting characters.

Comment: Have you tried  to [debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) your code?

Comment: please post your check_list() implementation

Comment: Also, you can just say `if(isspace(s[i]))` instead of `if(isspace(s[i]) != 0)`. Nothing related to your problem though, just writing cleaner code ;)

Comment: you know your algorithm is overwriting `tmp->val` every following iteration right? Use `strtok`, malloc tmp->val, and strcpy the token.

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to tokenize the string instead of implementing your own algorithm and append the parts to your linked list. Use `strtok` ([ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)).

From the link above.. example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:
> This
> a
> sample
> string
> ```

Comment: That's great, works perfectlty for parsing command line arguments with a bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 5):

**Better solution for The ANSI C.**

Usage *strtok()* it is not always good:

1. it will change an origin array.
2. separator of the space " " ignore similar characters: "\n", "\t" and other.

Try next and read comments for details:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // printf
#include <string.h>     // strlen, strncpy
#include <ctype.h>      // isalnum
#include <stdlib.h>     // malloc, calloc

/*
    A logical type
 */
typedef enum {
    false,
    true,
} bool;


/*
    A Struct for hold 2D-array with count items
 */
typedef struct _ListWithLength {
    char **list;
    size_t length;
} ListWithLength;


/*
    Parse a text and return pointer to a ListWithLength words and count it
 */
ListWithLength* getWords(char *text) {

    // a variable for count words
    int count = 0;

    // keep length of the text
    size_t text_len = strlen(text);

    // a flag indicating the a beginning of a word
    bool new_word = false;

    // an index of a start found a word
    int index_start_word = 0;

    // 2D-array for found word
    // it will be same memory size as the original text
    char **words = malloc(text_len * sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i <= text_len; ++i) {

        // if found ascii letter or digits and new no traced early
        // keep index of beginning a new word
        // and change the flag
        if (isalnum(text[i]) != 0) {
            if (new_word == false) {
                new_word = true;
                index_start_word = i;
            }

        // if it is not ascii letter or digits and a word traced early
        // it means the word ended
        } else {
            if (new_word == true) {

                // allocate a memory for a new word in the array of words
                words[count] = malloc(i - index_start_word * sizeof(char) + 1);

                // copy the found word from the text by indexes
                strncpy(words[count], text + index_start_word, i - index_start_word);

                // change the flag
                new_word = false;

                // increase the counter of words
                count++;
            }
        };
    }

    // bind the found words and it count to a structure and return it
    ListWithLength *list_with_length = malloc(sizeof(ListWithLength));

    list_with_length->length = count;
    list_with_length->list = words;

    return list_with_length;
}


/*
    Print information of a ListWithLength
 */
void printListWithLength(ListWithLength *list_with_length) {
    printf("Total items: %li\n", list_with_length->length);
    puts("----------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < list_with_length->length; ++i) {
        printf("%d. %s\n", i + 1, list_with_length->list[i]);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    char c_keywords[300] = "auto else    long    switch\
    break\t   enum \t register    typedef\
    \ncase    extern,  return  union\
    ?char    float.   short   unsigned\
    const   !for signed  void\
    continue    goto    sizeof  volatile\
    .default???? if  static  while\
    do  int struct,,,,  _Packed\
    double.......";

    ListWithLength *list_with_length = getWords(c_keywords);
    printListWithLength(list_with_length);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and see result:

```
$ gcc -Wall -ansi -std=c11 -o main main.c
$ ./main 
Total items: 33
----------------------
1. auto
2. else
3. long
4. switch
5. break
6. enum
7. register
8. typedef
9. case
10. extern
11. return
12. union
13. char
14. float
15. short
16. unsigned
17. const
18. for
19. signed
20. void
21. continue
22. goto
23. sizeof
24. volatile
25. default
26. if
27. static
28. while
29. do
30. int
31. struct
32. Packed
33. double
```

Comment: Isn't there a missing parenthesis in `malloc(i - index_start_word * sizeof(char) + 1)` ?

Comment: It seems to me that having the _option_ of treating different whitespace characters differently is positive, once the need to handle '\t' etc. is realized.  Consider the problems you would have with strtok() if it lumped them together when you needed to handle them differently.